# Find the integration for $3x e^{-3x}$ from $0$ to Infinity؟

Tags: calculus, integration

Find
$$\int_{x=0}^\infty3xe^{-3x}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
Could you please help me find the integral of the product of two functions?

Comment: Have you studied integration by parts?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: $\int_{0}^{\infty} 3xe^{-3x}dx = -\int_{0}^{\infty} -3x e^{-3x}dx = -\int_{0}^{\infty} x (e^{-3x})' dx$, then you integrate by parts.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $$\int e^{x} \cdot (f(x) + f'(x)) = \int \frac{d}{dx}\left\{ e^{x}\cdot f(x)\right\} = e^{x} f(x) +C$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint to get you started:

You use the method of [Integration by Parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) whenever one of the functions that make up the product differentiates to a constant eventually. For example; if you had $3x^2$ as the first function in your question then you would have to integrate by parts *twice*.

So proceeding with the integration:

> $$\displaystyle\int_{x=0}^\infty3xe^{-3x}\,\mathrm{d}x=-3x\left(\frac{e^{-3x}}{3}\right)\Big|_{x=0}^\infty+\int_{x=0}^\infty\left(\frac{e^{-3x}}{3}\right)\cdot 3\,\mathrm{d}x$$
> $$=\displaystyle-x\left({e^{-3x}}\right)\Big|_{x=0}^\infty+\int_{x=0}^\infty\left({e^{-3x}}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

The first term on the RHS vanishes and you are left to integrate $$\int_{x=0}^\infty\left({e^{-3x}}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$$ if you do this correctly you should get $\dfrac{1}{3}$ as the answer.